# escaping/encoding characters ready for use in an attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, razor, kendo-ui

**Context:**

I want to pass a title field into an Angular attribute. The title field is sometimes crazy with the characters people put in.

I have the following Csharp property:

```
Model.StoryTitle = "!"£$%^&*()<>;><~andanythingelsethatisweird";

<my-directive-thing story-title="@Model.StoryTitle"></my-directive-thing>
```

I also have this on a page that pulls the same field out of an Ajax call and gets populated by Kendo (darn legacy frameworks):

```
<my-directive-thing story-title="#= storyTitle #"></my-directive-thing>
```

On my directive side, I have the following code:

```
var storyTitle = $attrs.storyTitle || "";
```

**Issue:**

Due to the issue of having weird characters sometimes, I decided to escape it on the javascript side:

```
<my-directive-thing story-title="#= escape(storyTitle) #"></my-directive-thing>
```

The job was then easy as I put an unescape in the directive:

```
var storyTitle = unescape($attrs.storyTitle) || "";
```

Then everything works fine.

However, I don't know an equivalent for the Csharp.

**Question:**

Is there a trick I'm missing on the JavaScript + Csharp way of making sure ugly characters don't break attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Escape those characters or transform those characters to HTML enteties. You should not do that on your client side. Your backend should deliver nice encoded/decoded data.

```
Model.StoryTitle = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("!"£$%^&*()<>;><~andanythingelsethatisweird");
```

**> [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation**